# Find all objects in an ArrayList that satisfy a list of criteria in Java

Tags: java, sorting, search, properties, binary-search

For a concrete example, I have a class `City` that looks like this:

```
public class City {
    private String name;
    private int total; // total population
    private int men;   // male population
    private int women; // female population

    // constructor and getters...
}
```

I want to write a method that can take a list of `City` objects and a list of criteria (`total`, `men`, `women`) and return all the objects inside that satisfy these criteria. Each criterion has a range so I can for example search for all cities that has the total population between 1000, 2000 **AND** the female population between 200, 300.

I think we can create a class `Criterion` that looks like this:

```
public class Criterion {
    String crit;
    int min; 
    int max; 

    public Criterion (String crit, int min, int max){
        this.crit = crit;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
}
```

Then we can pass a list of of these `Criterion` objects with range to the method. Is this a good way to solve this? What do I need to sort first in order to use binary search? What is the general idea to deal with this problem?

Comment: Who's generating these criteria? Any reason you can't use a simple `Predicate<City>`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't overcomplicate the task. You can simply pass your list and a [`Predicate<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) representing the criteria to the method.

example:

```
List<City> findAll(List<City> cities, Predicate<City> predicate){
     List<City> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
     for (City city : cities) 
          if(predicate.test(city))
              accumulator.add(city);
     return accumulator;
}
```

then call it as follows:

```
findAll(cities, c -> c.getTotal() >= 1000 && c.getTotal() <= 2000);
findAll(cities, c -> c.getWomen() >= 200 && c.getWomen() <= 300);
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: (Lambda)

The cleanest way is to pass in a lambda.  I'm sure there will be 5 examples of this by the time I'm done typing...

Solution 2: (reflection & Annotations)

If your criteria (String) refers to an attribute name then you are involving reflection. Using java you can't get from a String to class or method name without it--it's what reflection is.

If you decide to use reflection you might want to also use annotations so that you aren't tying your strings directly to field names.  If you use field names and a user decides they want to use a naming pattern like "CITY_MEN < CITY_WOMEN" to supply the query, then you end up with fields named "CITY_MEN" and "CITY_WOMEN" which works but can get ugly after a while.

Also--Always remember when using reflection that your type checking, etc. moves from compile time to run time... these are actually pretty annoying penalties and require you to be extra cautious about validating your data.

Solution 3: (scripting)

If you are going to accept the penalties of reflection anyway then there is another alternative--Java has a javascript scripting engine built in.  You can tell the javascript engine about your object then just pass in a query, for instance:

```
findCities(cities, "city.men < city.women");
```

Your method, findCities, would create the javascript engine, pass in each city in order then tell it to execute that line.  It will return a Boolean if there is a match.  Magic.  I just implemented this so I could load my queries from a text file and it was faster than I thought and pretty clean to implement.

The advantage here is an absolutely trivial implementation, the disadvantages can be trivial to significant depending on how your search terms are supplied.

Answer (score 0):

The Criterion object can be replaced with [Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

Specification is a design pattern, which allows combining criteria using boolean operations into more complex logic compositions.

Say, we want to filter all cities including only the ones that have:

1. Population higher than X;
2. But lower than Y;
3. Regardless of the
   population, we want to include all the cities that have more women
   then men.

We need to place somewhere logic like:

```
population > x && population < y || men < women
```

Specification is just an interface with single method `isSatisfiedBy(city)`, that determines if an object matches all criteria and should be included into result list.

```
interface Specification<T> {
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(T t);
}
```

Then we need to have some logical composition objects, all of them implementing `Specification` interface:

```
class Or<T> implements Specification<T> {
    Specification<T> left;
    Specification<T> right;
    Or(Specification<T> left, Specification<T> right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(T t) {
        return left.isSatisfiedBy(t) || right.isSatisfiedBy(t);
    }
}

class And<T> implements Specification<T> {
    Specification<T> left;
    Specification<T> right;
    And(Specification<T> left, Specification<T> right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(T t) {
        return left.isSatisfiedBy(t) && right.isSatisfiedBy(t);
    }
}

class Not<T> implements Specification<T> {
    Specification<T> specification;
    Not(Specification<T> specification) {
        this.specification = specification;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(T t) {
        return !this.specification.isSatisfiedBy(t);
    }
}
```

Then we will need basic Specifications that can specify required properties of a City.

```
class MaxPopulation implements Specification<City> {
    private final int max;
    MaxPopulation(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(City city) {
        return city.getTotal() <= this.max;
    }
}

class MinPopulation implements Specification<City> {
    private final int min;
    MinPopulation(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(City city) {
        return city.getTotal() >= this.min;
    }
}

class HasMoreMen implements Specification<City> {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(City city) {
        return city.getMen() >= city.getWomen();
    }
}
```

And these City Specification be combined together, using previously defined logical Specifications, so our combined specificaton would look like this:

```
Specification<City> spec = new Or<City>(
    new And<City> (
        new MinPopulation(60000),
        new MaxPopulation(100000)
    ),
    new Not<City>(new HasMoreMen())
);
```

Following that filtering would be easy, we just need to pass the specification a parameter:

```
List<City> filtered = cities.stream().filter(city -> spec.isSatisfiedBy(city))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (City eachCity : filtered) {
    System.out.println(eachCity.getName());
}
```

Criterion object from original question could be expressed as a Specification, yet we are flexible to adjust business rules in any way we want:

```
Specification<City> criterion = new And<City>(
        new And<City>(new MinPopulation(1000), new MaxPopulation(2000)),
        new And<City>(new MinFemalePopulation(200), new MaxFemalePopulation(300))
);
```

(here `MaxFemalePopulation` and `MinFemalePopulation` need to be defined)

Often Specification uses Builder pattern that allows building of the specification using "fluent interfaces":

```
Specification<City> criterion = new SpecBuilder::from(new MinPopulation(1000))
    .and(new MaxPopulation(2000))
    .and(new MinFemalePopulation(200))
    .and()
    .build(MaxFemalePopulation(300));
```

Sorting can be done after filtering, because there will be less items to sort:

```
Collections.sort(filtered);
```

To call this method we need our city to implement `Comparable`:

```
class City implements Comparable<City> {
    private String name;
    private int total;
    private int men;
    private int women;
    public City(String name, int total, int men, int women) {
        this.name = name;
        this.total = total;
        this.men = men;
        this.women = women;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getTotal() { return total; }
    public int getMen() { return men; }
    public int getWomen() { return women; }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(City city) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(city.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using Lambdas and chaining them together. Simple example of sorting by total population. You can chain your criterias together and dynamically instead of writing hard-wired logics

```
public List<City> sortByTotalPopulation(){      
    cities.sort((City a1, City a2) -> a1.getTotal() - a2.getTotal());
    return cities;
}
```